# Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.x.beans.Album)

Tags: java, android, serialization

**Aim & Problem** : I need to past an Object ArrayList in my Intent .. so i know that my Class must Implement a **Serializable**, but when i have tried to do that i get the following exception :

**Exception** : `Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = 
com.x.beans.Album)`

**Album.java**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Album implements Serializable{
    @JsonProperty
    private Integer id;
    @JsonProperty
    private Profil profil;
    @JsonProperty
    private String nom;
    @JsonProperty
    private String ext;
    @JsonProperty
    private ArrayList<Photo> photos;

    public Album() {
    }

    public Album(Profil profil, String ext) {
        this.profil = profil;
        this.ext = ext;
    }

    public Album(Profil profil, String nom, String ext,  ArrayList<Photo> photos) {
        this.profil = profil;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.ext = ext;
        this.photos = photos;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Profil getProfil() {
        return this.profil;
    }

    public void setProfil(Profil profil) {
        this.profil = profil;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return this.nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getExt() {
        return this.ext;
    }

    public void setExt(String ext) {
        this.ext = ext;
    }

    public  ArrayList<Photo> getPhotos() {
        return this.photos;
    }

    public void setPhotos( ArrayList<Photo> photos) {
        this.photos = photos;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All fields (`ArrayList<Photo>` and `Profil` in my example) Must Implement Serializable